# Kuzzle: How to use "_kuzzle_info" to sort documents

Tags: node.js, sdk, kuzzle

I need to get the latest 100 documents from a specific collection so i used the search function and `created` from `_kuzzle_info` to sort documents by their date of creation but i think i have an issue with nested items as `created` is inside `_kuzzle_info`. Here is my code:

```
var lastHundred = await kuzzle.document.search("myIndex", "myCollection", 
    {
      query: {

      },
      sort: {
        "_kuzzle_info.created": {
          mode: "max",
          order: "asc",
          nested_path: "_kuzzle_info"
        }
      }
    })
```

I searched all over internet but nothing worked.So how to use the `_kuzzle_info` in the sort options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kuzzle metadata](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/essentials/document-metadata/) are stored in the `_kuzzle_info` property of every documents:

```
{
  createdAt: '<timestamp>',
  author: '<kuid>',
  updatedAt: '<timestamp>',
  updater: '<kuid>'
}
```

In your code snippet you are trying to sort with the `_kuzzle_info.created` property but you should use `_kuzzle_info.createdAt`.